# Stack Overflow Gives Back 2015

Tags: discussion, community

What charities will we support? I guess this is perhaps in the hands of the moderators but perhaps some voting guide the decision maybe good idea.

Link: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/12/stack-overflow-gives-back-2015/?cb=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The decisions were made, and the money has been given: the blog entry is announcing the results.

In early December, an email from StackExchange asked each moderator to choose,  from a short-list.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps we can consider: https://buddhistglobalrelief.org/?